# How to I import and display my .csv file in a Beamer presentation?

Tags: latex, beamer, overleaf

I have a csv file called csv1.csv that looks like:

```
   name|surname|grade
   Maier|Hans,|A
   Huber|Anna|B
   Weißbäck|Werner|C
```

(So my csv is a table with 4 rows and 3 columns. There are tabular lines and not "|" in my csv file - like a spreadsheet.)
My actual file is a .csv file in my desktop that I imported in my overleaf. I have no idea why I am unable to simply display the table, let alone format it, using the [csvsimple](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.pdf) package. What I tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\csvautobooktabular{csv1.csv}
\end{table}
\caption{My File}
\end{document}
```

I just want to display my csv file in my beamer and format it a bit (capitalize headers, make them bold, etc) instead of pasting a screenshot of it. If there is any other package that can help me, please feel free to suggest! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By default `csvsimple` assumes commas as the column separator; but your `csv1.csv` uses pipe characters. So you'll need to specify `separator=pipe`.

The `\caption` should also go before the `\end{table}`. So this should work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\csvautobooktabular[separator=pipe]{csv1.csv}
\caption{My File}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Demo on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tnbwbwfbjpqg)
[image]
[image]

Comment: This does display the file, thank you! However, the displayed file is not in the form of a table. Instead, it is separated by commas.

Comment: @Amelia I've added a screenshot and a read-only link to my Overleaf project.

Comment: @imnothere Here's what my display looks like: https://www.overleaf.com/read/phbwpfvszcvm

Comment: @Amelia The `csv1.csv` in your project is different from what you have posted here in your question. Are you now using **commas `,`** instead of **pipes `|`**  in your .csv? If you want to use **commas** you should not use the `separateor=pipes` option. Only use this option if you are using `|` in your .csv. Also, delete the `Table 1` on the first line of the .csv.

Comment: @imnothere edited my question, the pipes were just to represent tables, sorry! I am neither using commas nor pipes. It is a normal csv file - contains a table like a spreadsheet. Do I need to convert it such that the resulting csv doesn't contain tables, but has commas or pipes?

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the example of the following [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146719/90657), you can get the following result

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
    
% file content grade.csv

% name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
% Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
% Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
% Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title frame}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Caption of table}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c}%
      \hline
      \bfseries Person & \bfseries Matr.~No.% specify table head
      \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
      {\\\hline\givenname\ \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
      \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that the *.CSV file is in the same work board and the data is separated by a ","

Comment: My .csv file is in the same work board but my data is in the form of a table. Do I need to edit it and separate it by commas? I used this code, simply replaced grade.csv by csv1.csv (my file name is csv1) but it didn't work.